# Php inbox thread where sender or receiver does not repeat in the table

Tags: php

Hi I am currently creating an inbox page using php but I have trouble because the data is repeating.

This is my data

```
sender     receiver     message
john       mark         hello
mark       john         how are you?
john       david        hello david
```

what I want to show is like the inbox in facebook messager where it only shows the reciever's name once.

This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once '../../config/database.php';

$thisSession = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$query = mysql_query("select * from private_message where p_sender = '$thisSession' or p_receiver = '$thisSession'  group by p_sender, p_receiver");

?>

 <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Inbox</h2>

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>              
<table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table bulk_action">

 <thead>
<tr class="headings">
    <th>Sender</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){ 
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

    ?>  
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <? if  ($row['p_sender'] == $thisSession) {?>

       <td><a href="../message/index.php?view=detail&s=<?=$row['p_receiver']?>"><?=$row['p_receiver']?></a></td>
       <?} else {?>

       <td><a href="../message/index.php?view=detail&s=<?=$row['p_sender']?>"><?=$row['p_sender']?></a></td>
       <?}?>

        <td><?=$row['p_message']?></td>
        <td><a href="../message/process.php?action=delete&id=<?=$row['p_id']?>">[Delete]</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php        


    }

}

?>

    </tbody>
</td></tr>
</table>
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked" style="    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">




                    </ul>
```

Comment: What you got so far? Show us the codes you've written.

Comment: okay I'll update my question